# Is there a way to move an element from inside a two dimentional array to another place in the array without moving the rest of the elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
arr = [['', '', '', st], 
       ['', s1, '', ''], 
       ['', '', '', ''], 
       ['', '', '', '']];
```

I want to move `st` to `s1` so it looks like this:

```
arr = [['', '', '', ''], 
       ['', st, '', ''], 
       ['', '', '', ''], 
       ['', '', '', '']];
```

Using the function: `function move(st, x, y)`
Is it possible to do this without defining new variables?
`st` is a String

Comment: so this `move` function would have to locate where `st` is?

Comment: Yes, either by `for` or `indexOf()`

Answer (score 0):

using [array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var move(arr, tgt, x, y) {
    return !arr.every(function(line, cy) {
        var cx = line.indexOf(tgt);
        if (cx < 0) {
            return true; // not found, keep going
        }
        arr[y][x] = tgt;
        arr[cy][cx] = '';
        return false;
    });
} // function will return true if tgt is found - no sanity checks on input x,y is done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
    Array.prototype.myMove = function(x1,y1,x2,y2, noop) {
        // Move element at x2,y2 to element x1,y1 
        // and "deallocate" x2,y2 with w/e you like. Default is an empty string
        noop = noop || '';
        arr[x1].splice(y1,1,arr[x2][y2]);
        arr[x2][y2] = noop;
    }
```

> arr.myMove(0,3,1,1);

Test:

```
"[
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "str1"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "str2",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ]
]"
```

Became :

```
"[
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "str2"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ]
]"
```

Also if you want to search a 2d Array you could do something like this:

```
Array.prototype.searchFor = function(needle) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i ++ ) {

        for (var j = 0; j < this[i].length; j++) {
            if (needle === this[i][j]) {
                return {
                    x: i,
                    y: j
                };
            }
        }

    }

    return null;
}


arr.searchFor("str1") -> Object {x: 0, y: 3}
arr.searchFor("str2") -> Object {x: 1, y: 1}
```

Test arr used:

```
var arr = [['', '', '', "str1"], 
          ['', "str2", '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '']];
```